# Error sending mail to some adresses

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I have a webshop application which sends mail after a customer has placed an order. For some valid emailadresses, mail is not sent and after a day a failure report is send to an administrator. Then after another day, a delivery error
mail is delivered. An example of such an email adres is thisismycustomer@kliksafe.nl and is listed below. 
Why is this mail not delivered ?

```
Delivered-To: steefd@gmail.com
Received: by 10.129.163.17 with SMTP id a17csp28932ywh;
        Thu, 19 May 2016 06:44:05 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.25.22.217 with SMTP id 86mr1161211lfw.117.1463665445801;
        Thu, 19 May 2016 06:44:05 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <>
Received: from web02.terra-preta.nl ([46.182.180.231])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 77si4488452lfx.97.2016.05.19.06.44.05
        for <steefd@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 19 May 2016 06:44:05 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 46.182.180.231 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postmaster@web02.terra-preta.nl) client-ip=46.182.180.231;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 46.182.180.231 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of postmaster@web02.terra-preta.nl) smtp.helo=web02.terra-preta.nl
From: postmaster@Web-02
To: steefd@gmail.com
Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 15:43:56 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01D1AD2C5310C7F00000001Fweb02.terra?pret"
X-DSNContext: 7ce717b1 - 1386 - 00000002 - C00402D1
Message-ID: <A1XvpFVjC0000000b@web02.terra-preta.nl>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

This is a MIME-formatted message.  
Portions of this message may be unreadable without a MIME-capable mail program.

--9B095B5ADSN=_01D1AD2C5310C7F00000001Fweb02.terra?pret
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Unable to deliver message to the following recipients, due to being unable to connect successfully to the destination mail server.

       thisismycustomer@kliksafe.nl




--9B095B5ADSN=_01D1AD2C5310C7F00000001Fweb02.terra?pret
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;web02.terra-preta.nl
Received-From-MTA: dns;Web-02
Arrival-Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 14:17:40 +0200

Final-Recipient: rfc822;thisismycustomer@kliksafe.nl
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7

--9B095B5ADSN=_01D1AD2C5310C7F00000001Fweb02.terra?pret
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Received: from Web-02 ([127.0.0.1]) by web02.terra-preta.nl with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Tue, 17 May 2016 14:17:40 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Dev test" <steefd@gmail.com>
To: thisismycustomer@kliksafe.nl
Date: 17 May 2016 14:17:40 +0200
Subject: Munthandel Kevelam BV. Testing email functionality.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Return-Path: steefd@gmail.com
Message-ID: <WEB-021XvpFVjCRGryW00000047@web02.terra-preta.nl>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 17 May 2016 12:17:40.0758 (UTC) FILETIME=[1B8FB360:01D1B036]

Email works fine.



--9B095B5ADSN=_01D1AD2C5310C7F00000001Fweb02.terra?pret--
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and both of their `MX` servers respond just fine, which means that they blocked your SMTP server from connecting for some reason.

Apparently your server is not on any common blacklist, so they must have elected to block it for other reasons which could be anything, but possibly because your SMTP server's IP doesn't have a `PTR` record, which makes it suspicious.

Add a `PTR` record and if the problem persists after 24 hours, you'll have to check with the abuse departments of each system that refuses your mail until you get it sorted out.

It might be wise to use your own domain related email addresses and adjust your `SPF` record to include your `SMTP` servers to give your messages more credibility when they reach the destination servers.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will ask my domain provider to add a PTR/reverse DNS record. I also have asked kliksafe.nl what the error "Status: 4.4.7" means. According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232118.aspx this could be as well a mailbox full situation which explains the delay. On the other hand, if I mail this person direcly using gmail, there's no problem.

Comment: Your error message indicates that your SMTP server can not connect to the destination server.  At this point in the operation, the destination server does not know the address you're sending to.

Comment: What makes you say that ? It takes a day for the failure to occur, wouldn't the failure occur immediately of the destination server doesn't know the recipient adress?

Comment: You misread my last comment.  The remote server connection doesn't even go through, so that server still has no clue what email address you're trying to send to.

Comment: So your saying the mail is not leaving my server because it doesn't know where to go to ?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that the connection between your server and the destination server is blocked, probably on the remote end.